# What is the meaning of null in Mage log (magento)?

Tags: magento, logging

In order to create Magento log, one would write something like

```
 Mage::log('Server Side Validation kicked in for Year for '.$currentYearType);
```

But if I were to add the log in a sepearate file , do I

```
Mage::log('Server Side Validation kicked in for Year for ' ,null,'serversidevalidation.log');
```

Please correct me if I am wrong.

If so, what is the use of null in the middle?
Also, does the file need to exist before hand or I think it is created by system when needed. Am I right? Also, will it include timestamp?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Go to to `app/Mage.php`

line 785

```
public static function log($message, $level = null, $file = '', $forceLog = false)
```

you can see the second paramete is level

```
$level  = is_null($level) ? Zend_Log::DEBUG : $level;
```

**lib\Zend\log.php**

```
const EMERG   = 0;  // Emergency: system is unusable
const ALERT   = 1;  // Alert: action must be taken immediately
const CRIT    = 2;  // Critical: critical conditions
const ERR     = 3;  // Error: error conditions
const WARN    = 4;  // Warning: warning conditions
const NOTICE  = 5;  // Notice: normal but significant condition
const INFO    = 6;  // Informational: informational messages
const DEBUG   = 7;  // Debug: debug messages
```

if you this code `Mage::log('test', 1);`

then you get a output in log file like this

```
2014-05-17T12:21:51+00:00 ALERT (1): test
```

> **Yes, the file is automatically created by system when its call**
>
> **system include the timestamp when it call**

refer this code in `app/Mage.php` in line 825

```
 $format = '%timestamp% %priorityName% (%priority%): %message%' . PHP_EOL;
 $formatter = new Zend_Log_Formatter_Simple($format);
```

Cheers