# Where are Magento's log files located?

Tags: php, magento, error-log

I am new to Magento. I can't find log files in Magento. I googled it, but the [Magento Commerce](http://www.magentocommerce.com/) site returns closed and some other sites explain how to create custom log files. I want to know the location of built-in log files.

Comment: var/log folder on root..system.log and exception.log are the default ones

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You can find them in `/var/log` within your root Magento installation

There will usually be two files by default, `exception.log` and `system.log`.

If the directories or files don't exist, create them and give them the correct permissions, then enable logging within Magento by going to `System > Configuration > Developer > Log Settings > Enabled = Yes`

Comment: no need to create directories..magento creates them at runtime if not found

Comment: In a recent install of Magento 1.9, this wasn't the case for me and I had to manually create the directories.

Comment: exception.log and system.log are name of the file. What should the name of the directories be?

Comment: Both files should be within `/var/log/`, e.g. `/var/log/exception.log`

Answer (score 5):

To create your custom log file, try this code

```
Mage::log('your debug message', null, 'yourlog_filename.log');
```

Refer this [***Answer***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23710811/what-is-the-meaning-of-null-in-mage-log-magento/23711334#23711334)

Comment: Sir can you please tell me how to create a exception.log file in magento. I can see system.log file but there is no exception.log file

Comment: No need to create that file, it will automatically create that file when a exception occurs.
If you need to create that file, you can change the file name in 'yourlog.log' in the above code

Answer (score 0):

You can find the log within you Magento root directory under

```
var/log
```

there are two types of log files system.log and exception.log

you need to give the correct permission to var folder, then enable logging from your Magento admin by going to

```
System > Configuration> Developer > Log Settings > Enable = Yes
```

system.log is used for general debugging and catches almost all log entries from Magento, including warning, debug and errors messages from both native and custom modules.

exception.log is reserved for exceptions only, for example when you are using try-catch statement.

To output to either the default system.log or the exception.log see the following code examples:

```
Mage::log('My log entry');
Mage::log('My log message: '.$myVariable);
Mage::log($myArray);
Mage::log($myObject);
Mage::logException($e);
```

You can create your own log file for more debugging

```
Mage::log('My log entry', null, 'mylogfile.log');
```

Answer (score 0):

These code lines can help you quickly enable log setting in your magento site.

```
INSERT INTO `core_config_data` (`config_id`, `scope`, `scope_id`, `path`, `value`) VALUES
('', 'default', 0, 'dev/log/active', '1'),
('', 'default', 0, 'dev/log/file', 'system.log'),
('', 'default', 0, 'dev/log/exception_file', 'exception.log');
```

Then you can see them inside the folder: `/var/log` under root installation.