# How to create your own log file in magento

Tags: magento, system

I am new in magento , so can you please suggest me to how to create your own log file in folder var/log

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use

`Mage::log('<My Values>', null, 'mylog.log', true);`

Where `<My Values>` is what gets printed in your log file.

That should work all the time.

**Note: that your logs should be open from admin section**

Comment: Thank you sir , i am going to try this

Comment: [What is the meaning of null in Mage::log() parameter string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23710811/what-is-the-meaning-of-null-in-mage-log-magento) or how to set the level of message returns on Magento logging by setting the numeric value of the second parameter. Fourth parameter is forcelog=true/false which forces writing to the log even if logging is disabled in System Config=> Developer settings.